# Where to begin with WebDAV, Cloud storage, and Laravel

Tags: laravel, ms-office, webdav, minio

Is it possible to give users the ability to remotely edit documents that are stored in the cloud storage of my web application?
I know that with the webdav, you can remotely open and edit ms-office documents on the local machine and save files back to the cloud storage. I want to add this feature on my laravel web-application and i cant find the solution.
I heard about ITHit Webdav Library and i need something like this.

1. Do I need my own webdav server for this?
2. Are there any free solutions or libraries for this?
3. I use minio as cloud storage, can [this](https://github.com/totoval/mindav) library help me?

I need at least some guidance for this. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. Yes, you need your own WebDAV server, cloud storage providers typically don't have this built-in.
2. The most popular library for PHP would be [sabre/dav](https://github.com/sabre-io/dav)
3. It does not matter which cloud storage provider you use, with WebDAV it will work for most (if not all) and will definitely work with Minio. As for my recommended package, see above.

ITHit WebDAV Library is a commercial library and you should stick with open-source in my opinion.

Implementing it into Laravel would be quite opinionated, but doing so ultimately depends on what you need to achieve from a user experience and functionality perspective.

There is nothing simple about the road you're travelling and it is quite complex.